# TypeError: object of type 'function' has no len(), function called correctly?

Tags: python-2.7, typeerror

I am trying to write a simple code to translate a strand of DNA into RNA and return the corresponding proteins. I am receiving a TypeError on line 19 ("for i in range(len(y))"). The variable y will be a list. I have tried looking at other questions but none of their solutions are applicable to my code. I am confused because I thought the variables were called correctly. Can someone offer some insight?

Here is my code:

```
dna = 'ATGCTAGCTAGCTAGCTAGTATTATATAGCGCGATCGATCGATA'
dna_list = []

for char in dna:
    dna_list.append(char)

def rev_dna(x):
    rev_dna = []
    for char in x:
        rev_dna.append(x[len(x)-1])
        del(x[len(x)-1])
        return rev_dna

def translate(y,z):
    for i in range(len(y)):
        if y[i] == 'T':
            y[i] == 'U'
        z = "".join(y)
        return z

rna1 = ""
print translate(dna_list,rna1)
```

Comment: Your code has several issues, yet doesn't reproduce the error you mention: **1**. It is a bad idea to use the same name for a function and to a variable (`rev_dna`). **2**. It is also a very bad idea to delete items from a list while iterating over it. **3**. You can simply have `dna_list = list(dna)` instead of the first `for` loop. **4** I believe `return rev_dna` should be outside of the `for` loop.

Comment: 1. I can fix that issue
2. That function is based off code I have previously used (successfully) to reverse the order of a list. If you have a better way of doing that, let me know
3. That is the way I was taught to perform that function
4. That was a mistake I made when copying the code over to the question editor

Comment: 2. `li = reversed(li)` or `li = li[::-1]`.